# Difference between std::function<> and a standard function pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

Whats the difference between std::function<> and a standard function pointer?

that is:

```
typedef std::function<int(int)> FUNCTION;
typedef int (*fn)(int);
```

Are they effectively the same thing?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A function pointer is the address of an actual function defined in C++. An `std::function` is a wrapper that can hold any type of callable object (objects that can be used like functions).

```
struct FooFunctor
{
    void operator()(int i) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
};

// Since `FooFunctor` defines `operator()`, it can be used as a function
FooFunctor func;
std::function<void (int)> f(func);
```

Here, `std::function` allows you to abstract away exactly what kind of callable object it is you are dealing with — you don't know it's `FooFunctor`, you just know that it returns `void` and has one `int` parameter.

A real-world example where this abstraction is useful is when you are using C++ together with another scripting language. You might want to design an interface that can deal with both functions defined in C++, as well as functions defined in the scripting language, in a generic way.

**Edit:** *Binding*

Alongside `std::function`, you will also find `std::bind`. These two are very powerful tools when used together.

```
void func(int a, int b) {
    // Do something important
}

// Consider the case when you want one of the parameters of `func` to be fixed
// You can used `std::bind` to set a fixed value for a parameter; `bind` will
// return a function-like object that you can place inside of `std::function`.

std::function<void (int)> f = std::bind(func, _1, 5);
```

In that example, the function object returned by `bind` takes the first parameter, `_1`, and passes it to `func` as the `a` parameter, and sets `b` to be the constant `5`.

Comment: @makar It's the identifier used by `std::bind` to refer to the first argument of the resulting function. It's a bit like: `void bound(int _1) { func(_1, 5); }`.

Comment: [The link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848690/should-i-use-stdfunction-or-a-function-pointer-in-c) mentioned another different between function pointer and std::function: The lambda capture is unable to be used in function pointer.So if you try to use lambda `[&](int a, int b){/*blah*/}`, or `[=](int a, int b){/*blah*/}`, you will have a compile error. The only valid format is `[](int a, int b){/*blah*/}`

Comment: Using bind is no longer recommended. We have lambda's, which are a nicer mechanism. While `bind` is not deprecated - I wouldn't it make it look like I were promoting its use.

Comment: `std::function` may be more convenient but it will cost you some performance over the raw function pointer ,when used with `std::bind`.

Comment: The last example with std::bind looks a lot like partial application in functional programming. Didn't know such a thing was possible in C++.

Comment: ICYDK '_1' is defined in the std::placeholders namespace (I didn't know that at first, just looked it up).

Comment: For clarity) `std::function<void (int)>` `f(func);` or `f{func};` or `f=func;` all works.

Answer (score 62):

They are not the same at all. `std::function` is a complex, heavy, stateful, near-magic type that can hold any sort of callable entity, while a function pointer is really just a simple pointer. If you can get away with it, you should prefer either naked function pointers or `auto`-`bind`/`auto`-lambda types. Only use `std::function` if you really need a systematic way of organizing a heterogeneous collection of callable entities, such as functions, functors, capturing lambdas and bind expressions.

---

*Update:* A bit of explanation about `auto` types: Compare the following two functions:

```
void do_something_1(std::function<void(int)> f, int a) { f(a); }

template <typename F, typename A> void do_something_2(F f, A a) { f(a); }
```

Now imagine invoking them with a lambda or a `bind` expression:

```
do_something_X([foo, &bar](int n){ bar += n*foo; },     12);
do_something_X(std::bind(X::bob, &jim, true, _1, Blue), 13);
```

The second version with the template is more efficient, because in both cases, the argument `F` is deduced to the actual, unknowable type of the expression. The first version, with `std::function`, isn't a template and may look simpler and more deliberate, but it *always* forces the construction of the `std::function` object, and quite possibly carries multiple type erasure and virtual dispatch costs.

Comment: This is kinda confusing, mind explaining this further?
that is, exactly when to use std::function, and when to use a function pointer. Also, what is a "auto-bind/auto-lambda types"

Comment: @aCuria: If you want to make a container of callable things and you want to put all sorts of mixed types in there, then you *have* to use `std::function` and convert everything. But if you know that you always have genuine free functions, you can just make a container of function pointers. I'll expand on the auto-preference in the actual post in a bit.

Comment: Do the calls to do_something in the update need a second parameter (corresponding to the `a` in `do_something_1` and `do_something_2`, or am I completely confused about how they're working?

Comment: @benw: Not at all, the confusion was entirely on my part - fixed! Thanks :-)

Comment: Function pointers won't work with **lambdas capturing context variables**. If you expect to use lambdas, `std::function` is a better choice.

Comment: @JanVčelák While this is true, the template can handle also lambdas capturing context. So when passing such lambdas you are not limited to use `std::function` but can also use templates.

Comment: Can I ask why you recommend function pointer over `std::function`? As per core guidelines it is generally more performant.
https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rt-fo

Answer (score 18):

A `std::function` has state. It can hold additional parameters "bound" into it.

These parameters can range from things like other classes, other functions, or even this pointers for member function calls.

The replacement function pointer is not `typedef int (*fn)(int);`

It is `typedef int (*fn)(void*,int);`, with the `void*` reperensting the state that would be hidden in the `std::function`.

Answer (score 9):

No.

One is a function pointer; the other is an object that serves as a wrapper around a function pointer.

They pretty much *represent* the same thing, but `std::function` is *far* more powerful, allowing you to do make bindings and whatnot.

Comment: Is there a simple way of converting between these two?

Comment: @phimuemue: That doesn't make sense in the general case.

Comment: @phimuemue You write a wrapper function that takes a std::function as the data pointer, and then calls the std::function. The function pointer must have a data pointer in order for this to work.

Comment: ... which is not a conversion.

Comment: -1 Not because it's incorrect, but imprecise and unclear. First, you should explain that `std::function` is a wrapper a round a callable object (such as a function pointer, but not limited to just that). Also, `std:: function ` is just a wrapper, you don't use it specifically to make bindings.

Comment: -1: Agreed with Paul. This answer needs more detail.