# How to write functions that use other functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Consider the following code, which is contained in a library of my making.

```
#include <complex>

std::complex<double> besselJ(int order, std::complex<double> z)
{
    // Function call
}

std::complex<double> besselH1(int order, std::complex<double> z)
{
   // Function call
}
```

Notice that both functions have the same signature. Now, I want to write a third function that does exactly the same thing whether it's acting on `besselJ` or `besselH1`. I tried the following

```
template<std::complex<double> (*T)(int, std::complex<double>)>
std::complex<double> diffBessel(int order, std::complex<double> z)
{
    return T(order-1, z)-T(order+1,z);
}
```

When a member function tries to use the syntax `diffbessel<besselJ>(int, std::complex<double>`, GCC complains that `the value of 'besselJ' is not usable in a constant expression`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2156899/1415916) for an explanation.

Is there a way to do something like the templated code above would do if it worked without resorting to wrapping `besselJ` and `besselH1` in `struct`s? I think structs would add unneeded complexity.

UPDATE: This works beautifully, as @aschepler suggested it should. There was a name collision in the actual code. It took that extra 1001th look to see it. I had been confused by other StackOverflow articles which suggested that this wouldn't work because the function pointer was mutable.

Comment: The linked answer doesn't explain why `diffbessel<besselJ>(args)` doesn't work.  And as far as I can see, it should work.

Comment: Can you show the exact code on which GCC complains?

Comment: Thanks to you both. It **does** work. I had overlooked a stupid mistake, even though I looked at the code for hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [function passed as template argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174169/function-passed-as-template-argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PREMISE:**

Provided that `besselJ` in your example is the name of the *function*, and not of a *variable* you are using as a template argument, then passing a function pointer as a non-type template argument *should* work.

See a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/NhL3i%2449).

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**

If your function pointer is held in a variable whose value is computed at run-time, you won't be allowed to use that function pointer as a template argument. If you want to use a run-time function pointer, you could just use a regular *function* argument rather than a template argument:

```
#include <complex>

std::complex<double> diffBessel(
    std::complex<double> (*fxn)(int, std::complex<double>),
    int order,
    std::complex<double> z
    )
{
    return fxn(order-1, z) - fxn(order+1,z);
}
```

**MORE IDIOMATIC SOLUTION:** (requires C++11)

If you want more flexibility, with C++11 you could use `std::function<>`:

```
#include <complex>
#include <functional>

std::complex<double> diffBessel(
    std::function<std::complex<double>(int, std::complex<double>)> fxn,
    int order,
    std::complex<double> z
    )
{
    return fxn(order-1, z)- fxn(order+1,z);
}
```

In both cases, your function could be invoked this way:

```
int main()
{
    std::complex<double> c;
    /* ... */
    diffBessel(besselH1, 2, c);
}
```

**FURTHER POSSIBILITY:**

As a further possibility, if you do not want or cannot use `std::function<>`, you could let your function accept any callable object by making it a template:

```
template<typename F>
std::complex<double> diffBessel(
    F f,
    int order,
    std::complex<double> z
    )
{
    return f(order-1, z) - f(order+1,z);
}
```

Again, you would invoke this exactly the same way as you invoked the previous versions.

Comment: I thought of using `std::function`, but in the [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054774/difference-between-stdfunction-and-a-standard-function-pointer) comparing `std::function` and function pointers, it is discouraged to use `std::function` unless the extra power is needed.

Comment: @JoeyDumont: The decision on whether or not to use `std::function` is based on your use cases mainly. `std::function` allows for more flexibility (you can pass in a lambda, a functor, anything), and its "bad" performance (a virtual function call in most cases) should become an issue for you only when you prove it to be a bottleneck. Otherwise, you should focus on clean design. This said, you do not *have* to use `std::function`. You could use a regular function pointer, but as a function argument, not as a template argument.

Comment: @JoeyDumont: Anyway, as I wrote at the beginning of the answer, a template argument should also work in your case, as long as you are not passing in the value of a *variable*. If you are, i.e. if the function to be used is determined at run-time, then you're pretty much forced to use a function argument rather than a template argument: whether to opt for a regular pointer or an `std::function` is up to you. Personally, I would go for the second one.

Comment: @JoeyDumont: There's one more possibility: make your function a template *and* accept the function as a function argument. See the last update to my answer.

Comment: Doesn't that last possibility imply that the functions should be in a `struct` or `class`?

Comment: @JoeyDumont: No, the last possibility accepts anything which is a callable object. Could be a function pointer, or the instance of a functor class.

Answer (score 3):

Templates need to know their parameters at compile time.  Pulling the template parameter out of a variable at runtime won't work.

Just make the function pointer a function parameter.  It doesn't need to be a template function.

```
std::complex<double> diffBessel(int order,
                                std::complex<double> z,
                                std::complex<double> (*T)(int, std::complex<double>))
```

Comment: Indeed, but this fails as I have another function that uses either the base functions `diffBessel`. I would need a variable number of function pointers, and that's awfully inelegant at best. Thanks for the idea, though.